# How to add new minutes value for every next array element?

Tags: javascript

I want to add 36 minutes for every next value in the array  but I get only one increase for all elements in array  how to implement an algorithm which I describe above

```js
let timestamps = [
    "2020-01-21T22:36:00.000Z",
    "2020-01-21T23:12:00.000Z",
    "2020-01-21T23:48:00.000Z",
    "2020-01-22T00:24:00.000Z",
    "2020-01-22T01:00:00.000Z",
]

const minutesToAdjust = 36
const millisecondsPerMinute = 60000
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
const twentyFourHours = new Date(new Date() - oneDay)

const transformTimeseriesTo24h = timestamps.map(el => {
    el =  new Date(twentyFourHours + (minutesToAdjust * millisecondsPerMinute))
    return el
})

timestamps = transformTimeseriesTo24h

console.log(timestamps)
```

Comment: I'm confused by what you want to do. "Every next value" sounds like you want to add 0 to the first one, 36 minutes to the second one, 72 (36 * 2) minutes to the third, ...?

Comment: You're setting the same value everywhere because `new Date(twentyFourHours + (minutesToAdjust * millisecondsPerMinute))` never changes for each iteration

Comment: You can run my code and see what i mean, i get "2020-01-28T15:06:54.000Z", for all values instead "2020-01-28T14:33:54.000Z" for second "2020-01-28T15:42:54.000Z" for third etc

Comment: @kikosko, are you voting everyone up just for the effort of answering?  That's gracious of you but not how SO works.

Comment: every question is correct so I voted everyone but i will choose most useful for me like a correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Date.parse(el)`

```js
let timestamps = [
  "2020-01-21T22:36:00.000Z",
  "2020-01-21T23:12:00.000Z",
  "2020-01-21T23:48:00.000Z",
  "2020-01-22T00:24:00.000Z",
  "2020-01-22T01:00:00.000Z",
]

const minutesToAdjust = 36
const millisecondsPerMinute = 60000
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
const twentyFourHours = new Date(new Date() - oneDay)

const transformTimeseriesTo24h = timestamps.map(el => {
  return new Date(Date.parse(el) + (minutesToAdjust * millisecondsPerMinute))
})

timestamps = transformTimeseriesTo24h

console.log(timestamps)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ignoring the original dates by immediately assigning to `el`. Instead, since they're valid ISO-8601 date/time strings, parse them then add 36 minutes to them:

```
timestamps = timestamps.map(el => {
    const dt = new Date(el);
    dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + 36); // Will wrap for you
    return dt; // Or `return dt.toISOString();`
});
```

Live Example:

```js
let timestamps = [
    "2020-01-21T22:36:00.000Z",
    "2020-01-21T23:12:00.000Z",
    "2020-01-21T23:48:00.000Z",
    "2020-01-22T00:24:00.000Z",
    "2020-01-22T01:00:00.000Z",
];

timestamps = timestamps.map(el => {
    const dt = new Date(el);
    dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + 36); // Will wrap for you
    return dt; // Or `return dt.toISOString();`
});
console.log(timestamps);
```

Or... "Every next value" sounds like you want to add 0 to the first one, 36 minutes to the second one, 72 (36 * 2) minutes to the third, ...? If so, you can use the index that `map` passes as the second argument:

```
timestamps = timestamps.map((el, index) => {
    const dt = new Date(el);
    dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + (index * 36)); // Will wrap for you
    return dt; // Or `return dt.toISOString();`
});
```

Live Example:

```js
let timestamps = [
    "2020-01-21T22:36:00.000Z",
    "2020-01-21T23:12:00.000Z",
    "2020-01-21T23:48:00.000Z",
    "2020-01-22T00:24:00.000Z",
    "2020-01-22T01:00:00.000Z",
];

timestamps = timestamps.map((el, index) => {
    const dt = new Date(el);
    dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + (index * 36)); // Will wrap for you
    return dt; // Or `return dt.toISOString();`
});
console.log(timestamps);
```

---

I couldn't tell whether you wanted to end up with `Date` instances of ISO strings. The above result in `Date` instances. If you want ISO strings instead, just call `toISOString()` on `dt` when returning it (see comments above).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use timestamp value from array and add your offset in that

```js
let timestamps = [
    "2020-01-21T22:36:00.000Z",
    "2020-01-21T23:12:00.000Z",
    "2020-01-21T23:48:00.000Z",
    "2020-01-22T00:24:00.000Z",
    "2020-01-22T01:00:00.000Z",
];

const minutesToAdjust = 36
const millisecondsPerMinute = 60000
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
const twentyFourHours = new Date(new Date() - oneDay)

timestamps = timestamps.map(time => new Date(new Date(time).getTime() + minutesToAdjust * millisecondsPerMinute));

console.log(timestamps)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would convert your time stamps to [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) add the 36*60 seconds to it, and convert it back to your format.